# VS Community 2015 Missing Template

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio Community 2015 when creating a new project, under templates C# -> Web I'm missing the "ASP.NET Empty Web Application"; in fact there is only one template available "ASP.NET Web Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `ASP.NET Web Application` from the options:

[image: New Project Dialog]

A new screen will be shown, and you'll see a list of templates. Select the `Empty` one for either ASP.NET 4.5.2 or ASP.NET 5.

[image]